# Exercise concerning a joint pdf

Tags: probability, density-function

A joint pdf $f(x,y) = c(x+3y)$ with  $0<x<1$ and  $0<y<4$.

A) Determine $c$;
B) Find the marginal pmf $g(x)$ and $h(y)$,
C) Are $x$ and $y$ independent

My attempt:

1. I set the double integral of $c(x+3y)$ equal to one and got $c=1/26$ but I'm a little shaky on my calculus.
2. I had trouble here. I set $g(x)$ equal to the integral of $f(x)$ but got pretty confused trying to figure everything out.

Comment: $c=1/26$ is correct .. $g(x) = \int_y f(x,y) dy$ and $h(y) = \int_x f(x,y)dx$.

Comment: You did the double integral, and did it right. Now what's the problem with two _single_ integrals of the same function, which will give you the marginal pmf's?